# NgRx dynamic switch case behavior parametrized selector

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I have a component where I get multiple data from different NgRx feature states. I'm not that fluent in RxJS and I struggle with the sequencing of the data flow.

The code below is run at component initialization :

```js
// UI related display context
this.displayContextId$ = this.store.select(selectCurrentDisplayContextId);
this.displayContextId$.subscribe();

// Data related to this component's parent
this.currentItem$ = this.store.select(selectCurrentItem);

// Some data from the state
this.featureAData$ = this.store.select(featureADataByItemId(this.subItem.id));
this.featureBData$ = this.store.select(selectfeatureBDataByItemId(this.subItem.id));

this.featureBData$.subscribe();

// Some data that needs featureAData to be fetched
this.featureCData$ = this.featureAData$.pipe(
    mergeMap(featureA => this.store.select(selectSomeDataById(featureA.someId)))
);

this.featureCData$.subscribe();
```

The pseudo code describes the essence of what I try to achieve and currently doesn't work :

```js
// When displayContextId changes, select one specific item from the store which is identified by an id issued of the concatenation of other ids (from the data model specs)

this.displayContextId$.pipe(
).subscribe(displayContextId => {
    switch (displayContextId) {
        case DisplayContexts.TypeA:
            this.displayContextItem$ = this.featureAData$.pipe(
                mergeMap(featureA => this.store.select(selectDisplayContextItemById(displayContextId + '-' + featureA.someId)))
            );
            break;
        case DisplayContexts.TypeB:
            console.log(d);
            this.displayContextItem$ = this.featureCData$.pipe(
                mergeMap(featureC => this.store.select(selectDisplayContextItemItemById(displayContextId + '-' + featureC.someId)))
            );
            break;
    }
});

this.displayContextItem$.subscribe();
```

I'm perfectly aware that it's not the RxJS manner of doing this. My goal is to dynamically reselect data from the store based on different input sources which are evolving during the component lifecycle.

Also, I don't know where to put this in the component lifecycle.

What could be a working implementation of this ?

Many thanks,

Comment: Did you think about high order selector instead?

Comment: High order selector is only possible for `currentItem` which is one level above `subItem`, also, the current item ID is stored in the state which make it possible to call `selectCurrentItem`. Since the component is used for many different `subItems` (I edited the code to make it clearer), it's not possible to store in the state an hypothetical `selectedSubItemId` to use in a high order selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators
....
this.displayContextItem$ = this.displayContextId$.pipe(
  // take the value of displayContextId and switch to a new observable depending on its value
  switchMap(displayContextId => {
    switch (displayContextId) {
        case DisplayContexts.TypeA:
            return this.featureAData$.pipe(
                mergeMap(featureA => this.store.select(selectDisplayContextItemById(displayContextId + '-' + featureA.someId)))
            );
        case DisplayContexts.TypeB:
            console.log(d);
            return this.featureCData$.pipe(
                mergeMap(featureC => this.store.select(selectDisplayContextItemItemById(displayContextId + '-' + featureC.someId)))
            );
    }
  }),
);
// after you initialized it, you can subscribe to it
this.displayContextItem$.subscribe();
```